# Silverlight Grid

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

Is it possible to have a countdown timer in a silverlight grid?

Comment: The answer is of course "Yes" however I doubt thats all you wanted to hear.  Care to elaborate your question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes: you can have any custom controls within a silverlight grid.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you need to be more specific about what you are attempting to do and what you have already tried.

But take a look at the [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28VS.95%29.aspx) class. It should enable you to do what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out you can include a timer in your grid. If it is a visual timer control you are looking then take a look at the following example:  http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Gauge/Gallery/TimeMonitoring

This gives a few good exmaples on how you might implement this. A timer control is not available from the SL toolkit.